# Woocommerce JS issue with Chrome only, product quantity numbers

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm on WordPress 3.8.1 running Agritourismo Child theme and Woocommerce 2.1.0. All of a sudden, I am having issues with products in Chrome only.

http://molinarimarket.com/market/

1. Can't adjust product quantities in Chrome, and "Add To Cart" button missing from main shop window (must go to individual products to add to cart).
2. Works fine in Firefox and IE

I think it is related to these js errors.

Also, next to the + - signs for product quantity there are up and down arrows, no need for duplicate buttons, very strange.

Answer (score 1):

The + and - signs are a part of Chrome/HTML5, but are obviously redundant with WooCommerce's buttons.  You can remove the Chrome ones with the following CSS:

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
}
```